# Plot has several small graphs on one page

Tags: r, plot

How do I plot only one graph on each page? The plot function plots graph on one page like in the screenshot until it's full. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Only if you tell it to via `par(mfrow=...)` or `layout()` or something similar. Try restarting your R session if you have some sort of hangover from previously submitted code.

Comment: If you want to undo setting `mfrow`/`mfcol` without restarting, set it to 1 row and 1 col, e.g. `par(mfrow = c(1, 1))`